# Centering two links in my footer

Tags: html, css

I have a question about CSS (perhaps some HTML if that is needed).

I'm making a .footer, but my two links – 'Host' and 'controlpanel' – won't center.

Wouldn't mind some help!
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjVZzW

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f75418;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div>
    <a style="float: left;" href="http://www.example.com">site map</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Controlpanel">Controlpanel</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" title="Host website">Host</a>
  </div>
  <!- start of freefind search box html ->
  <a style="float:right;position:absolute;right:20px;top:15px;">
    <form action="http://search.freefind.com/find.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self">
      <input type="hidden" name="si" value="000">
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="r">
      <input type="hidden" name="n" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="bcd" value="&#000;">
      <input type="text" name="query" size="15">
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
  </a>
  <!- end of freefind search box html ->
</div>
```

Note: I am very new to coding, so there might be some inefficient mistakes.
My desired end-result:

[image]

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWVGQB

Comment: Jonas, please show a picture of what you expect the end-result to look like, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified more, I meant the two links "controlpanel" and "host" but not the link "site map", thank you though.

Comment: Are we able to adjust your HTML to facilitate this?

Comment: Sure, from my perspective anything will make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your HTML a little bit, but you'll get the idea.

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="links-wrapper">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#">Link one</a>
      <a href="#">Link one</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <form  action="http://search.freefind.com/find.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self">
      <input type="hidden" name="si" value="80753354">
      <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="r">
      <input type="hidden" name="n" value="0">
      <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="bcd" value="&#247;">
      <input type="text" name="query" size="15">
      <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css :

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f75418;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
} 

.left{
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.middle{
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

.right{
  background-color: red;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}



.footer a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover, a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Hope this helps. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qLhLxqy/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Add all your anchors inside `footer` into `.footer-container` and wrap the two anchors you want centered inside `.center` div.

```
<div class="footer-container"> <!--Wrap all a inside container and position relative -->
    <a style="float: left;" href="http://www.example.com">site map</a>

    <div class="center"> <!--Wrap a you want centered -->
      <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Controlpanel">Controlpanel</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" title="Host website">Host</a>
    </div>

    <!- start of freefind search box html ->
    <a style="float:right;position:absolute;right:20px;top:15px;">
      <form action="http://search.freefind.com/find.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self">
        <input type="hidden" name="si" value="000">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="r">
        <input type="hidden" name="n" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="bcd" value="&#000;">
        <input type="text" name="query" size="15">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
      </form>
    </a>
    <!- end of freefind search box html ->
  </div>
```

ADD THIS CLASSES

```
.footer-container {
    position: relative;
 }

.center {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right:0;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f75418;
  text-align: center;
  border-top-style: dashed;
  border-width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer a:link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:visited {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover,
a:active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.footer-container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <a style="float: left;" href="http://www.example.com">site map</a>
    <div class="center">
      <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Controlpanel">Controlpanel</a>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com" title="Host website">Host</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!- start of freefind search box html ->
    <a style="float:right;position:absolute;right:20px;top:15px;">
      <form action="http://search.freefind.com/find.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self">
        <input type="hidden" name="si" value="000">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="r">
        <input type="hidden" name="n" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="_charset_" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="bcd" value="&#000;">
        <input type="text" name="query" size="15">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
      </form>
    </a>
    <!- end of freefind search box html ->
</div>
```